# Android ArrayList TextView does't show text after setText

Tags: android, arraylist, textview, show, settext

Hello I got some problems making an app and couldn't find the answer anywhere. 
I have an EditText for user input. I have a String word and I have an ArrayList with TextViews in it.
I want to set the text of a TextView based on if the user input equals a character from the String. If a character is equal it must be shown in the right TextView.
The problem now is that if I put in a character that should match with a character from the word, it doesn't show me anything, even when I want to show the StringBuilder in another TextView it looks like it is empty.

I have this:

```
public void onClickButtons(View view) {
    if(view==mBtnGuess) {
        String getInput = mEtxtUserInput.getText().toString();
        word = "someword";
        if(getInput.length()==1) {
            List<TextView> txtCharArr= new ArrayList<TextView>();
            txtCharArr.add(mChar1);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar2);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar3);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar4);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar5);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar6);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar7);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar8);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar9);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar10);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar11);
            txtCharArr.add(mChar12);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(i=0;i<getInput.length();i++) {
                if(getInput.equals(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)))) {
                    txtCharArr.get(i).setText(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)));
                    sb.append(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `word.length()` you are using `getInput.length()`

```
for(i=0;i<getInput.length();i++) {
                if(getInput.equals(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)))) {
                    txtCharArr.get(i).setText(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)));
                    sb.append(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)));
                }
            }
```

Hence you will only loop once and check the **getInput** for only the first char of **word**, which is **s**.

Comment: Tried it but it gives the same result

Comment: Now I see it I feel quite stupid. Spilled one day searching for answers. Thank you very much. haha